# How can I compare two JavaScript arrays in order to determine if they have identical values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't want to compare the two arrays as a whole, I specifically want to check if the 2nd array has any values that match a value in the first one. I then want to return the value that matches in both.

If I'm not mistaken, comparing two arrays as a whole would be done like this:

```
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [1,3,4];

console.log(JSON.encode(array1)==JSON.encode(array2));
```

So in this case, I would want to check if array2 has any matching values to array one, not if they both are equivalent. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Matching" - as in position and value or just value?

Comment: Just value, and I want to return the matching value/values.

Comment: you should update your question since your comment suggests you want to do more than just check...

Comment: Yup, updated it as soon as I posted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3],
    array2 = [1, 3, 4];

var AnyItemsOfArray1InArray2 = array1.some(function(item) {
    return array2.indexOf(item) > -1;
});
console.log(AnyItemsOfArray1InArray2);

var ItemsOfArray1InArray2 = array1.filter(function(item) {
    return array2.indexOf(item) > -1;
});
console.log(ItemsOfArray1InArray2);
```

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, could you explain what's going in in each part?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)